# How to make a space between characters

Tags: html, hyperlink

I am making a website on my computer and I have a navigation bar at the top. The links there look like they are part of a sentence, and so I'm trying to make a bigger gap between them. I have tried using spaces between the `<a></a>`'s, but the spaces didn't appear in the page.

HTML (Nav. Bar):

```
<div id='header'>
  <img id='tlogo' src="http://i.imgur.com/lVbnNwy.png?1">
  <a class="dif2" href="http://localhost:8080/Howl/Home.html">Home</a>
  <a class="dif2" href="http://localhost:8080/Howl/Rules.html">Rules</a>
</div>
```

Screenshot of the Nav. Bar:

[image]

Comment: Can you add the CSS too for the respective div which you have given.. and if possible provide a fiddle..

Comment: The screenshot has a practically unreadable nav bar, so you have much bigger problems than spacing.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela My mac shrunk the screenshot, so that isn't the actual size. The actual size is `width: 100%; height: 30px`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could add CSS

```
  #header a{
     display:block;
     padding:8px 16px;

  }
```

Comment: Oh, I didn't think about adding padding/margins! Mark this answer as accepted (in 10 min.)

Comment: Not a problem, glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this:

```
#header a{
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px; /*You can you whatever padding depending on your site*/
}
```

Hope this helps!!

Answer (score 0):

try putting 'nbsp;' where you want the empty space.
       http://jsfiddle.net/NA4DB/

```
   <div>Hello</div>
   <div>&nbsp;</div>
   <div>World</div>
```

Comment: error. you're not nesting your div's right. the fourth div tag should have a slash in it.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this css:

```
<style>
#header a{
     display:inline;
     padding:10px 15px;

  }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Its better to use `<ul>`s and `<li>`s

Home

Rules

```
 <style>
 ul.menu li {
 display:inline-block;
 padding:0px 5px 0px 0px;
 }
 </style>
```

Here is jsfiddle example [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/d8qG4/)

Answer (score 0):

like this:

```
<div id='header'>
  <img id='tlogo' src="http://i.imgur.com/lVbnNwy.png?1">
  <a class="dif2" href="http://localhost:8080/Howl/Home.html">Home</a>
  <a class="dif2" href="http://localhost:8080/Howl/Rules.html">Rules</a>
</div>
```

Style below:

```
#header > a {
  float:left
  margin-left:5px;
}
```